# 'System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(System.Drawing.Image)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, drawing

So, I'm just beginning C# today in hopes of creating a screen shot program. Originally, I was looking into using AIR to accomplish this, as I know a lot more when it comes to web development. None the less, I watched this [tutorial](http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=125) ([the code I'm trying to use](http://screensnapr.com/e/J7woj5.png)). It shows the **very** basics of how to get a screen shot.

Therefore, I tried to copy what I saw in the video over to C#, but I get the following error:

```
'System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(System.Drawing.Image)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace ShareFastCommand {

    class Program {

        static void Main(string[] args)  {

            int left = 10, top = 10;

            int right = 20, bottom = 20;

            Bitmap    b = new Bitmap(right - left, bottom - top);

            Graphics  g = new Graphics.FromImage(b);

            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(left, top, right - left, bottom - top);

            g.CopyFromScreen(left, top, 0, 0, r.Size);

            b.Save("C://Users/Josh Foskett/Desktop/test.png", ImageFormat.Png);

        }

    }

}
```

I'm using `Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express`.

I've tried Googling the error, among other things, and can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the problem line:

```
Graphics g = new Graphics.FromImage(b);
```

What the error message is telling you is that you don't need to say `new` there, just

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
```

The `FromImage` function already will create a `new Graphics` object for you.

Comment: Wow, I knew it was going to be something obvious. Thanks!